# React Native calling a function to open a dialog in render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, native, jsx

I am using this library (https://github.com/jacklam718/react-native-popup-dialog/blob/master/README.md) in my react native app to open up a dialog. So far, I followed the example code that they have and it works well for me:

```
import PopupDialog from 'react-native-popup-dialog';

<View style={styles.container}>
  <Button
    text="Show Dialog"
    onPress={() => {
      this.popupDialog.show();
    }}
  />
  <PopupDialog
    ref={(popupDialog) => { this.popupDialog = popupDialog; }}
  >
    <View>
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    </View>
  </PopupDialog>
</View>
```

The problem i have is opening the dialog when my screen first loads. I tried doing something like:
     {this.popupDialog.show()} and {() => this.popupDialog.show()} and other variations that didn't work. I want to be able to open the dialog w/out having to click a button to get the onPress() function to call. Can anyone guide me in the right place please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use the components lifecycle to call the `popupDialog.show()` function.

try adding this to your views script:

```
var self = this;
componentDidMount() {
   self.popupDialog.show();
}
```

find out more about the state and lifecycle in react at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Hope this helps.